# I have tried the quick fix options but the result is same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class Raycast_Script : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject spawn_prefab;

    GameObject spawned_object;

    bool object_spawned;

    ARRaycastManager arrayman;

    List<ARRaycastHit> hits=new List<ARRaycastHit>();


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        object_spawned = false;
        arrayman=GetComponent<ARRaycastManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount>0)
        {
            if(arrayman.Raycast(Input.GetTouch(0),hits,TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
            {
                var hitpose = hits[0].pose;
                if(!object_spawned )
                {
                    spawned_object=Instantiate(spawn_prefab,hitpose.position,hitpose.rotation);
                    object_spawned=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    spawned_object.transform.position = hitpose.position;   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is:

| Severity | Code | Description | Project | File | Line | Suppression State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error | CS1503 | Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Touch' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2' | Assembly-CSharp | C:\Users\tengi\planedetection\Assets\Raycast_Script.cs |  |  |

Comment: GetTouch(0).position???? perhaps

Comment: Please use tags a bit more careful .. this issue is not specific to the IDE you are using (visual-studio) nor to your target platform (android) and the Unity Game Engine has absolutely nothing to do with unity-container ..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the [ARRaycastManager documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/manual/raycast-manager.html), from the 2 Raycast functions available, you want the 1st one whose the signature is :
`public bool Raycast(Vector2 screenPoint, List<ARRaycastHit> hitResults, TrackableType trackableTypes = TrackableType.All)`.

The issue you're facing comes from the 1st parameter you gave to the function : `arrayman.Raycast(Input.GetTouch(0),hits,TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon)`.

[Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) returns a [Touch struct](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html), not a Vector2 as expected by the `Raycast` function. However, among the struct fields, you have [position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) which has a Vector2 type.

As a result, you need to change your if condition by : `arrayman.Raycast(Input.GetTouch(0).position,hits,TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon)`

Comment: Why do people downvote an answer that references documentation? Are you kind of jealous? When you first started learning programming, you would have been happy to find such an answer explaining and referencing the necessary elements.